# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat ") prints only 1 line

Tags: java, android

as discussed in various posts, I used

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -r 100 -f /sdcard/log.txt *:E");
```

command, to save logcat to text file. I wrote this line in `OnCreate()` method of mainactivity

I have also granted permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>
```

However, log.txt shows only 1 line

```
-------beginning of main
```

Can anyone tell me, how to print whole logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have also granted permission

First, permissions are case-sensitive, and therefore your permission is wrong.

Second, only apps installed on the system partition, or apps signed with the firmware's signing key, [can hold `READ_LOGS`, as of Android 4.1](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html).

> Can anyone tell me, how to print whole logcat

Ordinary Android apps cannot do this on modern hardware, for privacy and security reasons, as too many apps log too much crap to LogCat.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Problem was indeed in permission.